# How to import webform fields on server?

Tags: 7

I want to import fields of webform on server.Features will not include webform fields.
Is there any module by which I can import webform fields to server?

Comment: You mean defined forms? Or form results?

Comment: I mean defined forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Webform Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_import)

> Allows delimited data files to be imported as submission (results)
>   into webforms.
>
> This is useful for importing submissions from other systems in to
>   Webform. Can also be used to Edit submissions via Export / Import as
>   long as the CSV has the SID column filled.

2. [Webform Share](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_share)

> This is a helper module to prepopulate newly created webforms and to
>   export / import webforms between sites.

I think Webform Share module definitely solve your issue.